# Cannot debug with Xcode after OS upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, xcode, debug

I have a pesky problem that I can't solve without some help: I had Leopard
10.5.8 installed on a Mac Pro and Xcode 3.1.3 and yesterday I upgraded to
SL. After the upgrade, something happened to the existing Xcode because I
couldn't build anymore (xcodebuild could not be found by my build tools).

So I installed Xcode 3.1.3 again thinking that a refresh would fix the
problem. It didn't and I ended up with 2 Xcode apps - one in
/Developer/Applications and one in /Xcode 3.1.3/Applications (when I
reinstalled Xcode it wanted to install in /Xcode 3.1.3, and there wasn't an
option to install  in the default location -/Developer).

Next step was to delete both /Developer and /Xcode 3.1.3 and reinstall
Xcode 3.1.3. Again it wanted to install in /Xcode 3.1.3 and it still didn't
work. Fine, I said, I'm tired of fiddling with this, I'm installing Xcode
3.2. Which I did and it installed in /Developer.

Now I can build using Xcode 3.2 but I can't debug from Xcode. When I launch
a debug session I get this message in the GDB console: "Exception: starting
task (/Developer/usr/bin/gdb) ; name: NSInvalidArgumetException, reason:
working directory doesn't exist."

If I invoke gdb from a terminal prompt it works fine. Any suggestions on how
to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xcode 3.1.3 won't work with SL, you need 3.2, which comes with the DVD.  that much you've  figured out already (but honestly, something similar happened to me; can't the SL installer see that xcode is installed and suggest to me to install 3.2??).

i don't know exactly what happened to your setup, but i would guess that the uninstall/reinstall of 3.1.3 on an OS with which it's not supposed to play nice with has messed something up.

i would suggest trying:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

which will cleanly remove all xcode, and then reinstall xcode 3.2 (again), and seeing if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what version it is, but there is a new xcode supplied with snowleopard which should fix your problem.

Comment: That's Xcode 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this too, and uninstalling didn't work, but deleting the XCode preferences files did.